# Accessing the previous element in $('.class').each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to access the previous or next element while in a certain iteration of a `$('.class').each() loop;` Where the elements with class 'class' are not siblings?

I was able to do this by traversing through the DOM tree. But I was wondering if there is a more concrete and elegant solution.

Current code:

```
$('.slider-range').each(function(index){
  var temp = $(this).closest('.panel').next('.panel').find('.slider-range');        
  //do something with temp
});
```

Comment: @SudharsanS "where they are not siblings"

Comment: Need HTML to know what siblings are where and position of other surrounding elements don't ya think?

Comment: @zer00ne not really, no

Comment: @kd394 depends on your definition of "previous element" vs ".prev() element".  OP knows they can't use .prev() because they are not siblings, hence the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m I would need it to make a working demo, it would take me too long to guess.

Comment: @zer00ne the question is about items in the iteration of a loop, eg `for (var i = 0; i<10; ++i) { prev = i-1; }` ie the item in the previous iteration of that loop - not their placement in the DOM tree.

Comment: Ok, a collection then, I see.

Comment: Previous element is the element which was being accessed in the previous iteration of the loop. el.prev() simply returns the directly preceding sibling of el doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to "store" the "selected" items in a variable and use the index passed to the callback like this:

```
var range = $('.slider-range');
range.each(function(index){
    var temp = index > 0 ? range[index - 1] : null;        
    //do something with temp
});
```

I added a condition on the value of the index, to make the `temp`variable `null` if index is `0`.

**Edit:** Corrected with `index -  1` to "select" the previous item.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you have access to the current `index` within the collection of jquery objects.

```
$('.slider-range').each(function(index){
  var temp = $(this).closest('.panel').next('.panel').find('.slider-range');        

  //do something with temp
});
```

You can use this to get any of the other items in that collection:

```
var items = $(".slider-range");
items.each(function(index) {
    if (index > 0)  {
        var prev = items[index-1];
        // do something with prev
    } 
});
```